# Understanding Map Of Map

Tags: apex, map

Can some one kindly explain me the practical use case of `Map<Id, Map<Id, Map<Id, String>>>` as I am under confusion under what scenario we need to take such type of Map, kindly dont explain with dummy data or else kindly refer some map related links.

Comment: It's going to be hard (perhaps impossible) for anyone to give you a decent answer without using an example involving dummy/mock data. Generally, the point of providing examples is to illustrate a concept that you can then take and apply to your own situation. Can you go into detail about why you're putting that very burdensome requirement in your question?

Comment: @Derek Honestly thanks for your reply, okay i am open with dummy data too if it is ciritical to explain, i am reviewing a code in my office so i am not able to understand why they have used such map so i need to understand why and when we have make use of such scnerio.

Comment: @VishalReddy you would use a data structure like that to maintain relationships between objects. Let's say in this map maintains a hierarchy of Accounts to Cases. Accounts can be related to another account (Parent Account) so the outer map of IDs could hold Parent Account IDs. Each account ID leads to a map of child Account IDs. Cases are related to Accounts, so the second map associates Cases to Accounts. Finally the inner map, which holds a String - CaseStatus. While I wouldn't call this the most ideal way to represent this hierarchy, it is a possible example.

Comment: @nbrown thank you for your answer it was very helpful to understand the concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A map of maps works much like a [tree data structure.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) That is likely the best example of this kind of data structure you will be able to find documentation on. If you visualize a map of maps (using `Map<String, Map<String, String>` as an example) it would look something like below. So if you want to get "F" out of the inner map, you would need to first pull the Map for "A", then "C" from that map.
[image: Map of Maps structure]

Answer (score 2):

This type of map would be used when you have three related records (e.g. child, parent, grandparent, or child, grandchild, great-grandchild, or three siblings on a single related record, etc), and you want to find a value based on those three records. Note that this type of map can always be replaced with a [composite key](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm), as each layer in the nested map represents one part of the composite key you're using.

---

## Example Composite Key Implementation

```
public class Key {
  public Id a, b, c;
  public Key(Id a, Id b, Id c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
  }
  public Boolean equals(Object o) {
    Key other = (Key)o;
    return a == other.a && b == other.b && c == other.c;
  }
  public Integer hashCode() {
    return System.hashCode(a) ^ System.hashCode(b) ^ System.hashCode(c);
  }
}

Map<Key, String> values = new Map<Key, String>();
...
for(sObject row1: list1) {
  for(sObject row2: list2) {
    for(sObject row3: list3) {
      values.put(new Key(row1.Id, row2.Id, row3.Id), roe3.get(someField));
    }
  }
}
```

Using a composite key requires more "boilerplate" (as demonstrated above), but will shorten the main data population and retrieval code; it's more of a trade-off.

Comment: thanks for your reply can you kindly give me some practical example using standard objects

Answer (score 2):

Like other [data structures](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections.htm), i.e. Sets, Lists, Maps, this is also a data structure with nested Maps or multi-dimensional in other words.

**Why do we go with nested maps (or lists)**

Creating a nested data structure you form a parent-child hierarchy, which you can use to  refer to the child data of the collection by referring the parent or looping through parent within child and so on.

E.g. Account > Opportunity > OpportunityLineItems

Comment: your input too is valuable to build our own logic thanks for your valuable time